# How to downgrade from Marshmallow to Lollipop? Please help

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

So I've tried everything and it's not working, I cannot uninstall Marshmallow from my settings. I don't know what to do. Btw i have Lenovo A70000.

Answer (score 2):

The **official** status is that you **can not** downgrade.

But if *you* take the risk you can do the downgrade via `SP Flash Tool`, just follow this steps:

Preparing

- download an official stock ROM ([MM stock ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-a7000/development/lenovo-a7000-as223160405-row-andoid-6-0-t3360467#post66404777), [LP stock ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-a7000/development/stock-firmware-lenovo-a7000-t3205521))
- download and install phone drivers
- unpack downloaded stock ROM on your PC
- enable USB debugging option on your phone: like [this](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm)

  - Go to Settings > About > Build number > tap it 7 times to unlock Developer options > then return to Settings > Developer options > tick the USB Debugging option

Flashing via `SP Flash Tool`

- Charge your phone up to 80% and disable all those firewalls or antivirus on your PC.
- Run as Administrator the flash_tool.exe, that you will find in the stock rom package.
- Click on `Scatter-loading` and browse the scatter file `MT6752_Android_scatter.txt`
- In the menu `Option` tab, go to `Download`, and put `ticks` in the `DA DL All with Checksum` both USB and Storage Checksum.
- Now choose the `Download only` option
- Now hit the green `Download` button
- Now turn off the phone and remove the battery for at least 5 seconds, then put the battery back.
- Connect your Phone to PC via USB, this will start the flashing process.
- Once the process has completed, we will see a huge green check box.
- Now we can disconnect the phone from the cable.
  Now switch on your phone, it will take 6-10 minutes for first boot.
- You have successfully installed the stock ROM or Official ROM on Lenovo A7000 ROW version

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-a7000/how-to/downgrade-to-lollipo-marshmallow-t3410235)